# JS doesn't follow .then sequence for discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequence

Hello dear SO community,

I'm struggling with the script for my discord bot. I would like that my bot auto-react to a specific word. But I would like that the sequence of the reactions are chosen by myself, so I also defined the sequence but putting .then in the script, but I don't know why the bot is jumping around. I tried an official bot which also had the same problem then me and then tried ANOTHER bot but this one worked fine.

Here is an image of the sequence error, I would like that my bot reacts with 3 emojis, 0, 1 and 2 in the correct sequence, but sometimes there are errors upcoming and he's reacting the wrong emoji at the wrong moment.
[example or sequence error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGsx9.jpg)

And here is also a little part of my script (which is used to react)
[part of my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5virT.png)

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === messageContent)
        message.react(emoji).then(msg => 
            {message.react(emoji1)}).then(msg => 
                {message.react(emoji2)}); 
                })};
```

Thank you for answering!

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Comment: Thank you Barmar